# Setting class property as argument from command line

Tags: php

I am struggling to understand how I can pass terminal commands into a variable with `$argv[1];` in command line when I start a script.

I want to set a variable with whatever is in `$argv[1]` which I would enter in command line.

Example terminal:

```
php script.php setting
```

Example code:

```
class script
{
  public $somesetting = argv[1];

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function main()
    while(true)
    {

    }



}

$script = new script();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you defined a constructor in your example, you would need to pass your argument into a constructor when creating the object. A constructor is always called when an object is created. Get the constructor to then assign the argument to class properties (called **variables** when using procedural) using `$this->` which refers to the class your in. You can then access `$test` by echoing the property direct as the visibility for this property was set to `public`. If the property was set to `protected` or `private`, then you would not be able to access this property outside of the class.

**Terminal:**

```
php test.php hello
```

**Script.php**

```
<?php

 class script
    {

        public $test; 

        function __construct($arg)

        {

            $this->test = $arg;

        }
    }

    $script = new script($argv[1]);

    echo $script->test . "\r\n";
```

**Output from Terminal**

```
Hello
```

Some recommend reading material to get you started:

- **Visibility:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
- **Constructors:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php